# How can I obtain the largest set of rows that share a common set of at least 4 columns?

Tags: r, matrix, subset, intersection

I have a matrix containing gene names and sample numbers.
Each row is a logical vector indicating the samples in which a gene was detected. Genes must appear in a minimum of 4 samples out of 8 to make it this far (still be in the matrix). i.e., all genes in this matrix appear in 4 or more samples.

```
       Sample1  Sample2  Sample3  Sample4 Sample5 Sample6  Sample7  Sample8 
gene1  TRUE     FALSE    TRUE     TRUE    TRUE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
gene2  FALSE    TRUE     FALSE    TRUE    FALSE   TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
gene3  TRUE     TRUE     FALSE    TRUE    FALSE   TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
gene4  FALSE    FALSE    TRUE     FALSE   TRUE    FALSE    FALSE    TRUE
gene5  TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    TRUE    FALSE    TRUE     TRUE
gene6  FALSE    FALSE    TRUE     FALSE   FALSE   TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
gene7  TRUE     TRUE     FALSE    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE     FALSE    FALSE
gene8  TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
```

I could also say I have the list of samples for which the latter was expressed, such as:

```
> gene1
[1] "Sample1"  "Sample3"  "Sample4"  "Sample5"
```

How can I obtain the largest set of genes (rows) that belong to a common set of 4 samples (columns)?

Edit: This question stems from trying to recreate this:

> Outlier analysis is based on the assumption that samples (cells) of
>   the same type also have a set of commonly-expressed genes.
>
> The outlier algorithm iteratively trims the low-expressing genes in an expression file until 95% of the genes that remain are expressed above the Limit
>   of Detection (LoD) value that you set for half of the samples.
>
> The
>   assumption is that the set of samples contains less than 50% outliers.
>   This means that subsequent calculations will only include the half of
>   the samples that have the highest expression for the trimmed gene
>   list.
>
> The trimmed gene list represents genes that are present above
>   the LoD in at least half the samples or the most evenly expressed
>   genes—though they might not be the highest or lowest in their
>   expression value.
>
> For the 50% of the samples that remain, a
>   distribution is calculated that represents their combined expression
>   values for the gene list defined above. For this distribution, the
>   median represents the 50th percentile expression value for the set of
>   data.

Comment: May be `m2 <- m1[rowSums(m1)>=4,]; apply(m2, 1, function(x) colnames(m2)[x])`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @akrun. Can you explain what your function is doing?

Comment: I'm not sure, since it's not clear to me what the apply function (x) is intended to do.

Comment: Could you please show the expected output in your post based on the example you showed?

Comment: I have updated the post to reflect what I am trying to do in reality with the data. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to find the genes that co-exist in any 4 of the samples. You could try something like:

```
n = 4               
combs = combn(seq_along(colnames(mat)), n, simplify = F)
Filter(function(x) length(x) > 1, 
       setNames(lapply(combs, function(i) names(which(rowSums(mat[, i]) == n))), 
                lapply(combs, function(x) paste0(colnames(mat)[x], collapse = "; "))))
#$`Sample1; Sample2; Sample3; Sample4`
#[1] "gene5" "gene8"
#
#$`Sample1; Sample2; Sample4; Sample7`
#[1] "gene3" "gene5"
#
#$`Sample1; Sample3; Sample4; Sample5`
#[1] "gene1" "gene5"
#
#$`Sample2; Sample4; Sample6; Sample7`
#[1] "gene2" "gene3"
```

Where "mat":

```
mat = structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), .Dim = c(8L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4", "gene5", "gene6", "gene7", 
    "gene8"), c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", 
    "Sample6", "Sample7", "Sample8")))
```

Comment: I think this might be what the OP wanted.  Anyway, will wait for the OP's response. (+1)

Comment: Thanks. I imagine this would give me a substantial number of Sample combinations when I have a list of 96 Samples, which is what I am working with. In this simplified example, the Sample combinations can be 4 _or more_ . In my data, I would have to compute all the combinations of 48 or more samples. Would this still be achievable without crashing my computer? I suppose I would then only need to find the combination with most samples.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what the expected result would be.  If "m1" is the initial logical matrix, create a subset of matrix ("m2") that has at least 4 TRUE per each row.  If you need the column names of the elements that are TRUE for each row, loop it using `apply` with "MARGIN=1"

```
m2 <- m1[rowSums(m1)>=4,]
apply(m2, 1, function(x) colnames(m2)[x])
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this might get me close to what I want, but short one step - this would tell me for each gene, in which 4 (or more) samples it was detected. I would still have to find the unique combinations in this list, and find the one with most occurrences, sort of like a `uniq -c | sort `.

Comment: @PinkSharpie Have you checked alexis_laz's solution? Please do update your post with the expected result so that it will be easier to code

Comment: Yes, currently replying to the post, but I think this brings me closer.