# Largest set of columns having at least k shared rows

Tags: r, algorithm, time-complexity

I have a large data frame (50k by 5k). I would like to make a smaller data frame using the following rule. For a given k, 0>k>n, I would like to select the largest set of columns such that k rows have non-`na` values in all of these columns.

This seems like it might be too hard for a computer to do on a big data frame, but I'm hoping it is possible. I have written code for this operation.

It seems my way of doing this is too complex. It relies on (1) computing a list of all possible subsets of the set of columns, and then (2) checking how many shared rows they have. For even small numbers of columns (1) gets too slow (e.g. 45 seconds for 25 columns).

**Question:** Is it theoretically possible to get the largest set of columns sharing at least k non-`na` rows? If so, what is a more realistic approach?

[@alexis_laz's elegant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009670/3346095) to a similar question takes an inverse approach to mine, examining all (fixed-size) subsets of the *observations/samples/draws/units* and checking which variables are present in them.

Taking combinations of n observations is difficult for large n. For example, `length(combn(1:500, 3, simplify = FALSE))` yields 20,708,500 combinations for 500 observations and fails to produce the combinations on my computer for sizes greater than 3. This makes me worry that it's not gonna be possible for large n and p in either approach.

I have included an example matrix for reproducibility.

```
require(dplyr)

# generate example matrix
set.seed(123)
n = 100
p = 25
missing = 25
mat = rnorm(n * p)
mat[sample(1:(n*p), missing)] = NA
mat = matrix(mat, nrow = n, ncol = p)
colnames(mat) = 1:p

# matrix reporting whether a value is na
hasVal = 1-is.na(mat)

system.time(
  # collect all possible subsets of the columns' indices
  nameSubsets <<- unlist(lapply(1:ncol(mat), combn, x = colnames(mat), simplify = FALSE), 
                         recursive = FALSE, 
                         use.names = FALSE)
)

#how many observations have all of the subset variables
countObsWithVars = function(varsVec){
  selectedCols = as.matrix(hasVal[,varsVec])
  countInRow = apply(selectedCols, 1, sum) # for each row, number of matching values
  numMatching = sum(countInRow == length(varsVec)) #has all selected columns
}
system.time(
  numObsWithVars <<- unlist(lapply(nameSubsets, countObsWithVars))
)

# collect results into a data.frame
df = data.frame(subSetNum = 1:length(numObsWithVars), 
                numObsWithVars = numObsWithVars,
                numVarsInSubset = unlist(lapply(nameSubsets, length)),
                varsInSubset = I(nameSubsets)) 

# find the largest set of columns for each number of rows
maxdf = df %>% group_by(numObsWithVars) %>%
  filter(numVarsInSubset== max(numVarsInSubset)) %>%
  arrange(numObsWithVars)
```

Comment: I think this might explode combinatorially if n and k were large. You might start by looking at `table(rowSums(is.na(dfrm)))`. That might put some bounds on hte size of the problem in your data and would be quick to implement. The possible combinations of 5K-columns is going to be quite large. Take a look at sapply(1:10, choose, n=5000) to get an idea of the magnitude of that aspect of the problem.

Comment: Does it have to be accurate? Crazy suggestion: your problem looks somewhat similar to computing jaccard similarity of a big set of documents. Starting from a matrix in which the column is 1 if different to `na`, 0 otherwise, you could compute jaccard similarity, then get a cluster of similar rows, and those would be an approximation to the solution of your problem. Actually, if you accept a bit less accuracy, you could use LSH minhash. Crazy idea I know, still, hope it helps.